# Deadlock graph: Show SQL statement containing the phrase "password"

Tags: sql-server

We need to debug a MS SQL Server 2014 deadlock situation. We got our deadlock graph, but the statement seems to contain the string "password", so the SQL is obfuscated ("`*password---...`"). Is there a way to turn this behaviour off and get the actual statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no trace flag or way to override this behavior.

If any statement has a restricted word in it, it will be overwritten with "-------" or "** restricted **". This is the same whether it is a trace, in cache, or using XEvents.

Comment: The only other option you have is to either to a packet capture or use some other type of TDS interceptor. Both have their limitations and downfalls.

Comment: Do you know where it states this in BOL?

Comment: @KennethFisher What, specifically, are you looking for in the statement? I don't believe there is a BOL article about it. an you give me an example?

Comment: I was hoping you knew of a place in BOL where it discusses that behavior.    A list of restricted words and the fact that you get the "-----" result.  Just a curiosity thing.

Comment: @KennethFisher Is this something that would be helpful? If so, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Don't go through any effort if you don't already know where to find it.  I'll take a look myself.  Just find it interesting and wanted to read up on it.